# MIDI decoder library

Tags: audio, decode, midi

I want to know a free C/C++ library that can load and decode MIDI files.
I will play it with alsa or DirectSound,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Juce](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php) is a C++ framework that has a [MidiFile class](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce/api/classMidiFile.html).

[PortMIDI](http://portmedia.sourceforge.net/portmidi/) is another framework with a [class for reading SMF](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/portmedia/) (SMF is an acronym for Standard MIDI File).